# highlight text when word There was inside the array using

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the words in the array are equal to the noun word blockquote
If the word is not equal or does not exist in the array "rebaz", do not highlight it
`const rebaz = ["something", "Hello", "BMW"];`
That's just an example, css
I want to javascript

```css
.highlight {
  color:white;
  background:black;
  line-height: 150%;
}
```

```html
<blockquote><span class="highlight">
 Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something  
</span></blockquote>
```

Comment: How far did you get, where did you get stuck? What JavaScript have you attempted, and what went wrong? In what way did it go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this will it work for your use case

```
const highlightWords = (text, wordsToHighlight) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`\\b(${wordsToHighlight.join('|')})\\b`, 'gi');

    return text.replace(regex, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
};


    const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "blockquote"];
    const text = "Hello testing something Hello testing something Hello testing something Saab"
```

Comment: thanks but i went just highlight  this word  "Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "blockquote"   if have in blockquote

Comment: I have edited the post again to clarify my question